# Who, if anyone, was the "witch with the blood of the lion and the wolf"?

Tags: a-discovery-of-witches

Right until the final episode, various characters quote a prophecy that says, more or less, "Beware the witch with the blood of the lion and the wolf, for she will destroy the Children of the Night," which drives a lot of the fear surrounding Diana (whom most people seem to take for that witch), though Satu often claims that she is that witch.

I  am unclear on whether the Children of the Night are vampires, as seems most likely, or all supernatural entities. Regardless, at the end of the show no one seems to have destroyed any of the supernatural groupings, and they seem on track to be stronger than ever, with the reason for their decline identified and addressed. They have only been in destroyed in the very metaphorical (and bigoted) sense that there are no longer legal barriers to intergroup couplings—that is to say, not in any sense at all, because the groups were *always* descended from daemons in the first place. This would be the destruction of vampires in rather the same way that the revelation of Neanderthal DNA in the human genome was the destruction of *Homo sapiens*.

Nor is it clear what the blood of the lion and the wolf is, or how Satu  or Diana would have it. (Sure, the latter is descended from daemons, but the whole point is that so is everyone).

So in the end, who was the witch of the prophecy, assuming that it was even correct or fulfilled?

Comment: A good prophecy is ambiguous enough that it can be retconned to fit whatever happens. "Not by the hand of man..." and all that.

Comment: @Ethan - I think that a good (i.e., real) prophecy makes a specific prediction that can be falsified or confirmed. Otherwise, it is no more fantastical than the many predictions that people make in real life. The prophecy that you referenced should have been perfectly clear to the person hearing it: he was a man in both senses in which the word (or equivalent) was used in his society, and so he knew that the person who killed the Witch-King, if anyone, would have to be a woman or not human.

Comment: It would not have been ambiguous to almost anyone in the human or elven cultures of Middle-Earth, in fact. If asked whether a woman was a man, or a hobbit or elf was a man, they would certainly have responded in the negative.

Comment: But "the prophecy about the destruction of the Children of the Night was as real as the Sunday newspaper horoscopes" would certainly be a fine answer to this question, if supported by evidence.

Comment: There is a very long tradition, stretching back through literature, folklore, and legend, of prophecies that are understood only after the fact.

Comment: You mention "the final episode" so I assume you are talking about the video adaptation, which I have not seen.  In the books this prophecy is mentioned but I don't recall that it played any large part in the dénouement.

Comment: @Ethan- Well, this is one that does not make sense after the fact, which motivated me to ask this question. And yes, I am asking about the TV series. But if the books clarify how or if the prophecy applies, that is a fine answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Children of the Night are definitely the Bright Born / vampwitch children as this is written in the books.

Blood of lion and wolf could mean Diana as she is made a Declemont + thought of as a lion herself.

I have no idea what destroy means though - since it seems she does the opposite!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  A direct quote from the book on the first point would be great if you can dig one up.

Answer (score 1):

In the piece of paper Diana gets from her Dad,  you see the Dark Prince with a wolf familiar and the White queen with a familiar of a lion... so could even be their child?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know if you also noticed, but after Diana was branded by Satu, Mathew calls her “ma lionne” ( meaning my lioness). In the second season, while being tortured by her brother, Louise says “yes brother, show her the wolf”, wanting him to show Diana his blood rage state. After all the spoilers I got, I became furious that there is no conclusive answer for it yet, as I’ve been told……so I decided to let my imagination pretends that it may be about their daughter and we may see it in another series or book -_- it may be about something else entirely, but since I didn’t finish watching and reading it yet it’s still just my theory

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that we seek answers grounded in the work, and not just personal theories.  You seem to be suggesting some hypothetical character who hasn't appeared yet; do you have any evidence for this character?

Answer (score 0):

Diana is the witch in question.

Lion blood she got from Phillippe when he blessed her with his blood vow.
The name Diana is the Roman equivalent of the Greek goddess of the hunt (Artemis) and wolves are part of her remit. When Phillippe takes Diana and Matthew to the old ruined temple and asks Artemis for a blessing, Artemis graces her to show her approval.
Also as Matthew is now part of Diana, by marriage and also as she shares her blood with him and he in turn shares his blood with her. So taking all this into consideration, she is the witch with the blood of the wolf.

The part of the prophecy saying "she will destroy the children of the night"...in the book it's made clear that the vampires have reigned supreme over all other creatures for centuries, and view witches and deamons as inferior. Diana 'destroys' the vampires rule and brings them down to size by decoding the 'book of life' and bringing the truth of all creature DNA to light.
Deamons previously viewed as the mad and weakest of creatures are now seen as the basis of all creature life.

Answer (score 0):

Diana was born on 13th August, so she is a Lion by sign. Matthew calls her "ma lionne," she is fearless and the female lion is the one who hunts in the pack.

Matthew is considered to be a wolf, mates for life, wants to build a family, he desired to became a father, a husband. The Children of the Night are related to the ideas that were drawn by the Convenant, which Diana with her superior powers brings down and with the new knowledge allows for a new era to rise where all species are linked.

This is my simple version of the prophecy. It relates to Benjamin being killed as he was one of the children of the night, he lived in the shadows waiting to appear before Diana and trying to take her as a wife to have his children as well.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  But if lion refers to Diana, and wolf refers to Matthew, then neither of them is fully the one referred to by the prophecy, so who is it?

Answer (score 0):

> Beware the witch with the blood of the lion and the wolf, for with it, she shall destroy the children of the night.

Seems to me that Matthew is both the lion (in his noble self), where he calls her, "ma lionne" or lioness and the wolf (in his blood rage self) when his sister Liousa refers to him being able to "show his wolf". Therefore he is both. Diana has taken his blood literally. Diana has his children, or figurative "blood" - two of them.

She is destroying the Children of the Night or the fact that the Creatures, the three non-human species, through her efforts seem to be moving toward genetically uniting, solving their issues and bringing them into the "light" by creating unity and transparency amongst all four species. The species will nolonger be Children of the Night because they will be whole and in community, they will be Children of the Light and probably come out as human genetic relatives at some point.